# Behaviour of getParameter()

Tags: java, servlets

I have a text field in html form.

`<input type="text" name="uname">`

Code to capture this text field in servlet class is:

`String userName = request.getParameter("uname");`

And I was doing something like this:

```
if(userName.equals("aj")){

}
```

Now the problem is, if I kept `uname` text field blank before submitting the form, I am not getting the `NullPointerException`.

Oracle docs says: 
**String getParameter(String name)**

> Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the parameter does not exist

Please clear my confusion.

Comment: Did you enter something in text box ? or any java script code written on form submit ?>

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I am keeping it blank to understand the behavior. No script is there. Only `html` with `servlets`

Comment: @AJ. As you quoted, the parameter exists right ?? check for emptiness.

Comment: Parameter does not exist means the form does not have a field uname

Comment: Ok.. My question exactly matches with that duplicate. Thank you all. I got my answer. Flaging this question as duplicate..

Comment: I gave you that answer also below ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter **exists** but its value is an empty String. So you do not get `NullPointerException`. To check if the value is setted or not, you'd better use this:

```
if ((userName != null) && !userName.isEmpty())
```

or (with `Apache Commons`):

```
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(userName))
```

It does **not exist** if there is no input with name `uname` in your HTML code. If you remove this input, you'll got a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter exists, because it exists on your form. it's just empty, you have to check the value if you want to see if something is filled in or not. The parameter itself will always exist if it's on your form.

Answer (score 1):

Change your form submit method `Post` to `Get` and see this `URL`

it will like

```
http://xxxx/x?uname=&otherparameters
```

So here, your uname is going with empty string, and so you are not getting `NPE`

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/37290474?noredirect=1

You are keeping it blank. Since the form parameter existed in HTML, you are always get that value empty.

And as you quoted ,

> **null** if the parameter **does not exist.**

check for emptiness, if you want to see any value there are not.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the raw HTTP request sent by the browser. Even though you leave the HTML input "uname" blank, it gets sent to the browser. Your HTTP request's body looks something like:

```
uname=&otherParameter=otherValue
```

The method HttpServletRequest.getParameter("uname"), therefore, does not return NULL, because the parameter "uname" is in the HTTP request's body. This is what it means by "parameter does not exist" in the Oracle doc.

Comment: Answer already given about 10 times. Do not add more answer, just +1 when you agree with one. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

> if I kept uname text field blank before submitting the form, I am not
>   getting the NullPointerException!

In html form if data fields are blank then it does not discard the field, it submits or passes with empty string for the data field thus you are not getting `NullPointerException`.

Which you can confirm yourself by post parameter of the request. You can use Firebug in firefox to such information.

In case there are no parameter available with parameter name then `request.getParameter` would return you null which you can confirm by `request.getParameter("uname1");`

Comment: Answer already given about 10 times. Do not add more answer, just +1 when you agree with one. Thx.

Answer (score -1):

Replace with

```
if (userName != null && userName.equals("aj")){

}
```

It's possible that `userName` is `null`. You need to test for that prior to calling a method.

Comment: Wrong. If it's not entered, it will be empty. It's null only if the field does not exist in the HTTP request (so in the HTML form).